# How to extract image src url omitting the "?" and query string?

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, url, preg-match-all

I use the following regular expression to get the url of a img-Tag:

```
$output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post_single->post_content, $matches);
```

However, $matches gives me the following results:

```
http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/dsc_842.jpg
```

-> This is fine.

```
http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/dsc_0546.jpg?w=640
```

-> This is not fine.

How can I change the regular expression in order to prevent cases where `?w=640` is included in my result?

Help is much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: `'/<img.+src=[\'"]([^?\'"]+)/i'`

Comment: Just to put my two cents in: as you're using Wordpress (on PHP), you could as well use the function [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) which is able to handle all your requirements right out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy make it like this:

```
$output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"?]+)[\'"?].*>/i', $post_single->post_content, $matches);
```

That way `([^\'"?]+)[\'"?]` first matches anything beside quotes and question marks and then requires one.

For example: https://regex101.com/r/yJ1yA1/1

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to propose another approach (with xpath and [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($your_html_here);
$images = $xml->xpath("//img/@src");
foreach ($images as $image) {
    $parsed = parse_url($image);
    print_r($parsed);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this regular expression:

```
 $string='<img src="path/to/image/file.jpg">';
 preg_match('/(?:\<img[\s].*?src=)(?:\"|\')(.*)?(?:\'|\")/',$string,$matches);
```

**$matches[1]** will give you the exact **src** attribute of the **img** tag, doesn't matter how many attributes you have in **img** tag.

Logically other option you can have is to explode(PHP) on '=' and then try to find src attribute this can be a better option.

Answer (score 0):

The other regex solutions either unnecessarily match the entire line or use suboptimal pattern syntax.  This is the smallest / most efficient regex pattern that you are going to find:

```
<img.*?src=['"]\K[^\'"?]+
```

([Pattern Demo Link](https://regex101.com/r/yJ1yA1/2))

It also uses no capture groups, so `preg_match_all()`'s output array will be 50% smaller/leaner.

Code ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/71b881726a02e22cc094c4e90fd11846994bce22)):

```
$wp_post_content='<img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/dsc_0546.jpg?w=640">
<img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/dsc_0547.jpg?w=1080">';

var_export(preg_match_all('/<img.*?src=[\'"]\K[^\'"?]+/i',$wp_post_content,$out)?$out[0]:[]);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/dsc_0546.jpg',
  1 => 'http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/dsc_0547.jpg',
)
```